# Ассиметричное кодирование/декодирование BigInt в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Требуется зашифровать BigInt любым надёжным ассиметричным алгоритмом и получить также BigInt. Я не нашёл ни одного достаточно надёжного алгоритма для того чтобы зашифровать именно число (BigInt) в NodeJS.

Шаблон функции

```js
function generateKeys() {
  // ...
}

function encodeBigint(input, pubKey) {
  // ...
}

function decodeBigint(input, privateKey) {
  // ...
}

const [pub, priv] = generateKeys()

encodeBigint(10n, pub) // 12345n
decodeBigint(12345n, priv) // 10n
```

Алгоритм должен быть относительно простым, надёжным и самое главное быстрым, способным шифровать десятки миллионов чисел за несколько секунд.

Ключом может быть что угодно, но желательно тоже BigInt

Comment: А что вы уже рассматривали и почему оно вас не устроило? Вообще формально любую последовательность байт можно считать BigInt.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Уже точно не помню, какие-то ноунейм решения(из-за чего и не устроили), у меня с бд приходит строка и я её парсю в BigInt и нужно отправить ответом зашифрованыый вариант, с возможностью расшифровать **другим** ключом, ключ для шифрования открыто может лежать в коде. P.S. Может и расшифровка не приведёт к ужасной катастрофе, но лишняя безопасность, не лишняя. Да и по шифрованию чисел впринципе мало информации. Но наводка на то что это просто набор байт поможет найти больше информации